# How do I set ProductDetail Page for different categories of product In Django?

Tags: django

I am new to Django. I am building a web store app.

**Case 1:**
I have a category for Phones with these Model:
'title',
'description',
'price',
'front camera',
'back camera',

**Case 2:**
I have another category for accessories with these Model:
'title',
'price',
'description',
'type'

**The problem:**
They both share the same ProductDetail Page...accessories detail is showing front and back camera as features which is akward although both are set to none.

**The Ask:**

How can I render different ProducDetail Page for different Categories

[ProductDetail page for Accessories](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NnAelz0niPBhRyyb7qLZh1XcAyiH_Xan/view)
[ProductDetail page for Phones](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UaunYRnAjN3LHs7zrAFLFQFUfPOAv6cq/view?usp=sharing)

Below is my template-

```py
 <div class="content-place px-3">
                    <h4 class="mt-3">{{ object.title }}</h4>
                    <h5 class="price-color">&#8358;{{object.price}}</h5>
                    <h6 class="text-muted"><i class="fal fa-map-marker-alt fa-fw"></i> {{ object.location }}
                    </h6>
                    <small class="text-muted">Posted on {{ object.updated_on }}</small>
                    <hr>
                    <p>BRAND: <span class="spec"> {{ object.brand }} </span></p>
                    <p>CONDITION: <span class="spec"> {{ object.condition }} </span></p>
                    <p>SCREEN SIZE: <span class="spec"> {{ object.screensize }} </span></p>
                    <p>DISPLAY: <span class="spec"> {{ object.display }} </span></p>
                    <p>FRONT CAMERA: <span class="spec"> {{ object.frontcamera }} </span></p>
                    <p>BACK CAMERA: <span class="spec"> {{ object.backcamera }} </span></p>
                    <p>OPERATING SYSTEM: <span class="spec"> {{ object.operating_system }} </span></p>
                    <p>COLOR: <span class="spec"> {{ object.color}} </span></p>
                    <p>RAM: <span class="spec"> {{ object.ram }} </span></p>
                    <p>STORAGE: <span class="spec"> {{ object.storage }} </span></p>
                    <hr>
                    <p>{{ object.description }}</p>
                    <hr>

                    <div class="contact-number">
                        <button id="phonebutton" class="btn pgn-success">View phone number</button>
                        <p>
                            <a href="tel: {{ object.agent.profile.phone }}" id="phonelink" class="phone_number">
                                {{ object.agent.profile.phone }} </a>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        {% if object.agent == user %}
                        <a class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm mt-3 mb-3"
                            href="{% url 'shopitapp:product-update' object.id %}">Update</a>
                        <a class="btn btn-danger btn-sm mt-3 mb-3"
                            href="{% url 'shopitapp:product-delete' object.id %}">Delete</a>
                        {% endif %}
                    </div>
                </div>
```

This is my View >

```py
class ProductDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Product

 

class ProductCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Product
    fields = ['title', 'description', 'location', 'price', 'category', 'brand', 'condition',
              'screensize', 'display', 'frontcamera', 'backcamera', 'operating_system', 'color', 'ram', 'storage', 'product_image1', 'product_image2', 'product_image3']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.agent = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)


class ProductUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Product
    fields = ['title', 'description', 'location', 'price', 'category', 'brand', 'condition',
              'screensize', 'display', 'frontcamera', 'backcamera', 'operating_system', 'color', 'ram', 'storage', 'product_image1', 'product_image2', 'product_image3']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.agent = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def test_func(self):
        product = self.get_object()
        if self.request.user == product.agent:
            return True
        return False


class ProductDeleteView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, DeleteView):
    model = Product
    success_url = '/'

    def test_func(self):
        product = self.get_object()
        if self.request.user == product.agent:
            return True
        return False
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use jinja in your template

```
{% if object.frontcamera is not none %}   
    <p>FRONT CAMERA: <span class="spec"> {{ object.frontcamera }} </span></p>
{% else %}
    do nothing
{% endif %}

{% if object.backcamera is not none %}   
    <p>FRONT CAMERA: <span class="spec"> {{ object.backcamera }} </span></p>
{% else %}
    do nothing
{% endif %}
```